# Como representar uma matriz em Prolog?

Tags: matriz, algoritmo-de-busca, prolog

Estou fazendo um trabalho em Prolog que consiste basicamente em um problema de busca, há um cenário em um ambiente bidimensional e deve-se traçar o caminho que um personagem deve seguir para chegar ao outro. Há alguns obstáculos e regras mas minha dúvida inicialmente é sobre como representar esse ambiente:

Ambiente 5 x 10 quadrados

```
 | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
 |---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
1|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
2|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
3|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
4|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
5|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
```

Comment: Por favor, poste um trecho do código que você já tem para termos uma ideia melhor do problema, sugiro que leia esse artigo da ajuda do site: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais comum de se representar matrizes em linguagens de programação que não possuem um tipo nativo para tal é através de uma lista de listas:

```
ambiente([[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_], [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_], ... [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]]).
```

No entanto, outras representações são possíveis. Uma lista em Prolog é sempre uma [lista encadeada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_ligada), de modo que para acessar o elemento `(m,n)` você precisaria percorrer os primeiros `m` elementos para achar a lista certa, e então os `n` elementos dessa lista, para achar a posição que quer:

```
posicao(0,N,[Cabeca|_],E) :-
    posicao_lista(N,Cabeca,E).
posicao(M,N,[_|Cauda],E) :-
    M1 is M - 1,
    posicao(M1,N,Cauda,E).

posicao_lista(0,[X|_],X).
posicao_lista(N,[_|R],X) :-
    N1 is N - 1,
    posicao_lista(N1,R,X).
```

Em alguns casos isso pode ser suficiente, mas em outros você pode preferir uma representação alternativa, com acesso mais rápido (porém com modificação mais difícil). Se seu ambiente é imutável, uma alternativa seria listar explicitamente o que tem em cada célula, através de uma série de fatos isolados. Por exemplo:

```
celula(0,0,x).
celula(0,1,y).
celula(0,2,z).
...
celula(0,9,w).
celula(1,0,a).
celula(1,1,b).
...
celula(4,9,o).
```

Outras representações intermediárias também são possíveis, tipo:

```
linha(0, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j). /* Substitua a,b,etc pelo valor da célula */
linha(1, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j).
...
```

No fim das contas não há um padrão, você escolhe a representação que for mais fácil e mais lógico pra você trabalhar, conforme o problema que está tentando resolver.